# Swift async load image

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I am working on show image from url async. I have tried to create a new thread for download image and then refresh on `main thread`.

```
func asyncLoadImg(product:Product,imageView:UIImageView){
    let downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.processdownload", nil)
    dispatch_async(downloadQueue){
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: product.productImage)!)
        var image:UIImage?
        if data != nil{
            image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            imageView.image = image
        }

    }
}
```

When I was trying to debug that, when it comes to dispatch_async(downloadQueue), it jumps out the func. Any suggestion? Thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27712427/2303865

Comment: :( not working, same error. The operations in back thread never be executed

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you explain it more specifically? I cannot understand

Comment: Add that UIImageView extension to your project and just load your image using `yourImageView.downloadedFrom(yourImageLink, ... )`

Comment: put the debug point inside the block, step-in button wont go into the block.

Comment: @JaniceZhan kindly make exact answer as correct answer , so that it benefits other to resolve issue , which gets maximum upvote

Answer (score 106):

**Swift 5.0+  updated Code :

```
extension UIImageView {

    
        func imageFromServerURL(_ URLString: String, placeHolder: UIImage?) {

        self.image = nil
        //If imageurl's imagename has space then this line going to work for this
        let imageServerUrl = URLString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
        

        if let url = URL(string: imageServerUrl) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

                //print("RESPONSE FROM API: \(response)")
                if error != nil {
                    print("ERROR LOADING IMAGES FROM URL: \(error)")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.image = placeHolder
                    }
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let data = data {
                        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                       
                            self.image = downloadedImage
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Now wherever you required just do this to load image from server url :

1. Using swift 5.0 + updated code using placeholder image :
   UIImageView.imageFromServerURL(URLString:"here server url",placeHolder: placeholder image in uiimage format)

Simple !

Comment: Does it help then make it correct answer and close the question.

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer because it's more succinct. :+1:

Comment: Could you write the same extension for Swift 3 ?

Comment: @Kirill updated Code in Swift 3 . Try it . Hope it helps to resolve your issue

Comment: The Swift 3 version doesn't work for me. I am getting: Use of instance member imageFromServerURL on type UIImageView; did you mean to use a value of type UIImageView instead? Any Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: just use this way : UIImageView.imageFromServerURL("here server url")  , if it dint work then post exact line you used to show image in imageview

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari I get the same error in swift 3 as pointed by recoilnetworks. this is the line : if let url = URL(string: item["ProfilePhoto"] as! String){ cell.imageView.image = UIImageView.imageFromServerURL(url) } Please give some solution

Comment: Which version of swift , let me know it must be greater than 3.0 . In swift 3.0 this soln works @mamta

Comment: you should use this :  if let url = URL(string: item["ProfilePhoto"] as? String not use ! (Force Wrapping operator like this ) it will cause crash . Still this answer suits it

Comment: Excellent code.  Easily best/simplest answer to this common issue. Thanks @ShobhakarTiwari!

Comment: @Waggoner_Keith  thanks , it helps to solve your issue

Comment: I'm using this code for display image in horizontal collection view inside tableview & when scrolling tableview  cells images conflict on imageview.how to solve it ?

Comment: updated answer , check it out by using self.image = nil .

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari i used above code in UITable the image only update after scroll and changed while scrolling.

Comment: i am updating it , check my new answer

Comment: Your update for Swift 5 is not compiling.
```let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()``` 

Gives error:
 ```Extensions must not contain stored properties```

Comment: Swift 5 is not compiling. Extensions must not contain stored properties.

Comment: it works when you load exactly one image only. If your `UIImageView` is set by multiple requests your code won't work

Answer (score 30):

Use `extension` in `Swift3`. To resolve **Network problem** i recommend you use `NSCache`:

```
import UIKit

let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, AnyObject>()

extension UIImageView {
    func loadImageUsingCache(withUrl urlString : String) {
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        self.image = nil

        // check cached image
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) as? UIImage {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        // if not, download image from url
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    self.image = image
                }
            }

        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Hope it help!

Comment: Why you used `NSString`, `AnyObject`,  instead `String`, `Any` ?

Answer (score 5):

Carrying on from Shobhakar Tiwari's answer, I think its often helpful in these cases to have a default image in case of error, and for loading purposes, so I've updated it to include an optional default image:

Swift 3

```
extension UIImageView {
public func imageFromServerURL(urlString: String, defaultImage : String?) {
    if let di = defaultImage {
        self.image = UIImage(named: di)
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error ?? "error")
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.image = image
        })

    }).resume()
  }
}
```

Comment: dont make duplicate answer , you can comment on answer so that developer get benefit from it

Answer (score 2):

This solution make scrolling really fast without unnecessary image updates.
You have to add the url property to our cell class:

```
class OfferItemCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var itemImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel! 
    var imageUrl: String?
}
```

And add extension:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
let imageDownloadUtil: ImageDownloadUtil = ImageDownloadUtil()

extension OfferItemCell {
    func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrl(urlString: String  ) {
         self.itemImageView.image = nil
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            self.itemImageView.image = cachedImage
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            imageDownloadUtil.getImage(url: urlString, completion: {
                image in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if self.imageUrl == urlString{
                        imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                     self.itemImageView.image = image
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

You can also improve it and extract some code to a more general cell class i.e. CustomCellWithImage to make it more reusable.

Comment: I am getting compile errors for ImageDownloadUtil. I can't see how it is declared and I am not sure how to make my own version of it.

Answer (score 1):

Here this code might help you.

```
   let cacheKey = indexPath.row
   if(self.imageCache?.objectForKey(cacheKey) != nil){
           cell.img.image = self.imageCache?.objectForKey(cacheKey) as? UIImage
    }else{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
             if let url = NSURL(string: imgUrl) {
                  if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                            let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data)!
                            self.imageCache?.setObject(image, forKey: cacheKey)
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                cell.img.image = image
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
```

With this image will download and cache without lagging the table view scroll

Comment: Awesome solution! But if i scroll fast i can still see the images changing from one to another, is there a way to avoid this or its impossible?

Comment: @Adrian Yes, you can check if image is nil or not, if it is nil you load it, if not - not.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way `in SWIFT 4` to load async images without `blink` or `changing images` effect is use to custom `UIImageView` class like this one:

```
//MARK: - 'asyncImagesCashArray' is a global varible cashed UIImage
var asyncImagesCashArray = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

class AyncImageView: UIImageView {

//MARK: - Variables
private var currentURL: NSString?

//MARK: - Public Methods

func loadAsyncFrom(url: String, placeholder: UIImage?) {
    let imageURL = url as NSString
    if let cashedImage = asyncImagesCashArray.object(forKey: imageURL) {
        image = cashedImage
        return
    }
    image = placeholder
    currentURL = imageURL
    guard let requestURL = URL(string: url) else { image = placeholder; return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestURL) { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            if error == nil {
                if let imageData = data {
                    if self?.currentURL == imageURL {
                        if let imageToPresent = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                            asyncImagesCashArray.setObject(imageToPresent, forKey: imageURL)
                            self?.image = imageToPresent
                        } else {
                            self?.image = placeholder
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    self?.image = placeholder
                }
            } else {
                self?.image = placeholder
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
}
```

example of use this class in `UITableViewCell` bellow:

```
class CatCell: UITableViewCell {

//MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var catImageView: AyncImageView!

//MARK: - Variables

var urlString: String? {
    didSet {
        if let url = urlString {
            catImageView.loadAsyncFrom(url: url, placeholder: nil)
        }
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the best way is to used [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Swift Example:

```
import SDWebImage
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "ImageUrl"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Objective C Example:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ImageUrl"]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

From Swift 5.5, its as simple as calling a function like:

```
imageView.setImage(url: myImageURL, placeholder: thePlaceholder)
```

using this simple extension:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func setImage(url: URL, placeholder: UIImage?) {
        self.image = placeholder

        Task { [weak self] in
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            self?.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that will use the `placeholder` until the image arrives from the network.