# How to load image from server to tableView cell in swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am trying to load news into the tableView and I did it. How do I load an image to the tableView cell next to the title?

I want the image to be loaded at the left side of the title.

host:
        https://api.sis.kemoke.net/news

image URL variable: imgUrl

Here is my class:

```
import Alamofire //Framework for handling http requests
import UIKit 

/*A class which will process http requests, receive the news as string and fill the array with such data which will be displayed in a table*/
class NewsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    //Custom struct for the data
    struct News {
        let title : String
        let text : String
        let link : String

        init(dictionary: [String:String]) {
            self.title = dictionary["title"] ?? ""
            self.text = dictionary["text"] ?? ""
            self.link = dictionary["link"] ?? ""
        }
    }

    //Array which holds the news
    var newsData = [News]()

    // Download the news
    func downloadData() {
        Alamofire.request("https://api.sis.kemoke.net/news").responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            //Optional binding to handle exceptions
            self.newsData.removeAll() // clean the data source array
            if let json = response.result.value as? [[String:String]] {
                for news in json {
                    self.newsData.append(News(dictionary: news))
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        downloadData()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return newsData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let news = newsData[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = news.title
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: What past related questions have you searched for and looked at?

Comment: Read the documentation for `UITableViewCell`, you might find something similar to `textLabel` that can help you.

Comment: chceck this both in swift 3 and 2.2 : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37019507/3400991 @Adin Ljudina

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the "best practice" to do something like this, is to create a custom cell (UITableViewCell) and a model class for each news. this scenario is something that every "swift tutorial site" have some example of it.
you can find some of them in these links:

http://www.kaleidosblog.com/swift-uitableview-load-data-from-json

https://grokswift.com/uitableviewcell-images-from-api/

Answer (score -1):

Swift 3
This code is tableview using image and label print in tableview cell get the api Json parse data

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

```
    var dict = array[indexPath.row]
    cell.lbl1.text = dict["address"] as? String
    cell.lbl2.text = dict["ad_created_date"] as? String
    cell.lbl3.text = dict["phone_number"] as? String
    cell.lbl4.text = dict["id"] as? String
    cell.lbl5.text = dict["ad_zip"] as? String

    let imageUrlString = dict["ad_path"]
    let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: imageUrlString as! String)!
    let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl)!
    cell.img.image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)



    return cell
}
```