# Show activity indicator until all images are load successfully

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, asynchronous, uiimageview

I have a collectionView cell which has five imageviews. I am using the following the answer given by javimuu to load images in the background. 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018916/swift-async-load-image)

It works well and all the images load in the correct imageview. But it is  very slow process and the images load in random order.
I am having difficulty in showing the activity indicator and hiding it when all the images are done loading for a specific cell i.e, Keep showing indicator while images are loading and hide it when all 5 images are loaded.

Please help.

Update:

```
    func downloadImageFromLink(link:NSURL,group: dispatch_group_t, completion:(isDone: Bool) -> Void) {

    self.image = nil

    imageURL = link.absoluteString
    dispatch_group_enter(group)

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(link, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if let imageFromCache = imageCache.objectForKey(link.absoluteString) as? UIImage {

            self.image = imageFromCache
            dispatch_group_leave(group)
            return
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

            let imageToCache =  UIImage(data: data!)

            if self.imageURL == link.absoluteString {
                self.image = imageToCache
                imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: link.absoluteString)
            }
            dispatch_group_leave(group)
        })
    }).resume()
}

func loadImagesInCell(cell: WatchFaceCell, images:NSArray ,completion:() ->Void) {
    self.startAnimating(cell.contentView)
    let group: dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create()
    for model in images{
        if model is WFCreatorModel {
            let wfModel: WFCreatorModel = model as! WFCreatorModel
            switch wfModel.imageType {
            case .Dial:
                cell.dialImage.downloadImageFromLink(wfModel.imageURL,group: group, completion: { (isDone) in
                })
            case .HourHand:
                cell.hourHandImage.downloadImageFromLink(wfModel.imageURL,group: group, completion: { (isDone) in
                })
            case .MinuteHand:
                cell.minuteHandImage.downloadImageFromLink(wfModel.imageURL,group: group, completion: { (isDone) in
                })
            case .SecondHand:
                cell.secondHandImage.downloadImageFromLink(wfModel.imageURL,group: group, completion: { (isDone) in
                })
            case .Notification:
                cell.notificationImage.downloadImageFromLink(wfModel.imageURL, group: group,completion: { (isDone) in
                })
            }//end of switch
        }//end of if else
    }//end of for
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.stopAnimating(cell.contentView)
        completion()
    }
}
```

Comment: The slowness might be due to images being large.  A quickie solution for knowing when all are done is to keep a counter: increment it before the dispatch async and decrement it (and check for zero) in the dispatch on the main queue.

Comment: @danh can you please explain with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to use a `DispatchGroup` which you can enter and leave when you make asynchronous requests. You then use the `.notify(queue:)` method which fires when the group is 'empty'. I was able to find an answer with code very similar to what you're looking for so I've linked it here:
[Wait until swift for loop with asynchronous network requests finishes executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906568/wait-until-swift-for-loop-with-asynchronous-network-requests-finishes-executing).

Let me know if you have any more problems. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried the dispatchGroup and it suits my needs but I am still facing an issue where the activity indicator  will quickly show up and vanish. It hits the dispatch_group_leave(group) where I am maintaining my cache 5 times and then hits the dispatch_group_notify call. But the images are not loaded in the imageView at that point. Calling them in the main_queue() causes the UI to lag, which was my original problem and hence all this code would be of no use.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the images are not loaded in the imageView at that point? They're not loaded when the notify function runs?

Comment: I mean to say I am assigning them an image after I get the result from NSURLSession, but since they are not running on the main thread they are not assigned immediately. If I run it on the main thread then the UI lags.

Comment: so you assign the images to their imageViews all at once in the dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

Comment: I will give that a try and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks it worked. Still a bit of lag remains when applying the image, but I guess that will always be there.

Comment: Ok, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a third party like kingfisher which will have all the necessary methods for performing such tasks.. Here is some sample code below just to give you something...

```
var prefetcher: ImagePrefetcher?
var imageItems: [ImageItem]? {
    didSet {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

// This code goes inside one of your methods
                      self.prefetcher = ImagePrefetcher(urls: urls, optionsInfo: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { [weak self]
                            (skippedResources, failedResources, completedResources) -> () in
                            self?.endLoading()
                            self?.imageItems = filteredItems
                            self?.timerLabel.countFrom(15, to: 0, withDuration: 15.0)
                            self?.timerLabel.completionBlock = { self?.startGuessing() }
                        })
        self.prefetcher!.start()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this does not solve my problem. How will I know that for a particular cell all 5 images have loaded? The example you have given is only for cached images and not for downloading images. I need to download each image separately so that I can set it for the correct imageView in the correct cell.