# I can't display images in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, collectionview

I want to display `UIImage` in `collectionView`.

Get Images Path from Json data.

The image path is acquired from the variable previously assigned
I am trying to display an image, but I can not get it.

API is working.

But I attempted to output it to check the value of the variable `var photo = [Stores.photos]?` But it was not displayed on the console

Also, if you apply imageURL directly, not from variable, the image will be displayed.
How can I assign a value to `var photo = [Stores.photos]?`

**StorePhotoCollectionView**

```
class StorePhotoViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var store_id = ""

var store : [Store]?
var photo : [Store.photos]?

@IBOutlet weak var mainImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var storePhotoUIView: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Request API
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/store/api?store_id=" + store_id)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let encoder: JSONEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

    session.dataTask(with: request){(data, response, error)in if error == nil,
        let data = data,
        let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse{

        let decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        do {

            let json = try decoder.decode(Store.self, from: data)


            self.store = [json]
            self.photo = json.photos

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.nameLabel.text = json.name
                self.locationLabel.text = json.location
            }

        } catch {
            print("error:", error.localizedDescription)

        }

        }

        }.resume()

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //UIView Corner redius
    let uiViewPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: storePhotoUIView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8))
    let uiViewMask = CAShapeLayer()
    uiViewMask.path = uiViewPath.cgPath
    storePhotoUIView.layer.mask = uiViewMask
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return photo?.count ?? 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let imageCell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath)
    let imageView = imageCell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

    print("asssss")

    let imageURL = URL(string:  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos/" + photo![indexPath.row].path)
    if imageURL == nil {
        print("nil")
    }else{
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL!)
            if let data = data{
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    imageView.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return imageCell
}

}
```

---

Comment: Check the URL in browser for the image.

Comment: Your url is http://localhost:8000, but in iPhone, has no localhost.

Comment: Did you reload your collectionView after get data from the API ? and also make sure photo?.count should not be 0

Comment: you forget to refresh your collectionview

Comment: @Kuldeep Im checked image URL in browser. Its can displayed

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Sorry. im biginner ios enginer. 
How do you draw the code when reloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget to refresh your collectionview, initially create the object for your collectionview

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourcollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

secondary on your main thread UI updation , refresh UICollectionView

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.nameLabel.text = json.name
            self.locationLabel.text = json.location
            yourcollectionView.reloadData()

        }
```

finally image loading from server , inhere you are doing the main thread call, it will freeze your app, for image showing process see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018916/swift-async-load-image)

Answer (score 0):

After calling dispatchque, try to add .resume()

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL!)
        if let data = data{
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                imageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: add `.resume()` got an error `Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'resume'`

Answer (score 0):

If I were you instead of manually handling the response etc I would simply use an open source library 
https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

The usage is simple enough that you won't have to handle these operations on your own:

```
imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: "your_url_here"))
```